# Will Facebook approve publish_actions permission if I want it only for Android app, and not for the iOS?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-permissions, publish-actions

We have developed social share feature (where users can share the post from status box of our app to Facebook). The problem is I want, and have done this work, only in our Android app but while submitting the permission for approval, it asks that I need to upload .ipa file also so, they can reproduce the steps at their end.

[image: Facebook Publish_actions permission]

Is it possible to get the publish_actions permission approved from Facebook only for Android ?

Comment: temporary delete ios app from Facebook Developer console and submit android app in review

Comment: The approval is tied to the app id, not specific platforms. You can not get a permission approved for a specific platform only. But if you simply explain to them in your review instructions, that you have implemented this in the Android version only, and just upload a dummy file instead of an IPA, you should be able to get it reviewed nevertheless.

Comment: @CBroe, Going to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @RaviRupareliya, I can't remove iOS app from Facebook Developer Console, because our iOS app is live and deleting iOS from Facebook will disable Login with Facebook in live app. 

I will try what CBore has suggested and see if it works.

Comment: @CBroe It worked and permission got approved. Thanks :)